# Adding code for TextView item in Navigation Drawer header

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I currently have a Navigation Drawer implemented inside my app using `NavigationView`. The layout of the drawer is split into a header `drawer_header.xml` and a menu `drawer_menu.xml`. It looks something like this:

[image: Drawer]

I am trying to set the user's name `DrawerNameTv` in the header in java code using `setText` instead of `xml` however I receive the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Here's the `Main_Activity.java`

```
TextView DrawerName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    CustomToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    DrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    DrawerName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DrawerNameTv);

    DrawerName.setText("Test");

    ...
```

And the `drawer_header.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/user_pic" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:id="@+id/DrawerNameTv" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Pardon me as I'm new to Android development.

Comment: You have not added the text view "DrawerNameTv" in your xml file

Comment: Check my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view `DrawerNameTv` is not found in the layout you're referring to and that's why its giving you a `NullPointerException`. You need to find the `DrawerNameTv` inside your `NavigationView` like this.

Inside your `onCreate` function

```
// lets change the variable names first.
private NavigationView mNavigationView;

mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
DrawerName = (TextView) mNavigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.DrawerNameTv);

// Now set the text here
DrawerName.setText("Test");
```

Comment: Please check the updated answer. you need to change the name of the `NavigationView` variable. `getHeaderView` function was called on the `NavigationView` class. Check the answer again and do the changes accordingly. Report me back and accept and upvote if helpful.

Comment: Thank you, there was a typo on my end. This solution worked marvellously. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

Add following function on your class.

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
   int id = item.getItemId();

    switch(id){
        case R.id.nav_home:
             // call your page from here
             break;
       case R.id.nav_message:
             // call your page from here
             break;
      case R.id.nav_setting:
             // call your page from here
             break;
    }

DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
            }
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. Why its getting the upvote?